# Чего не хватает в регулярном выражении?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, re

Есть список

```
urls = ['abc.ru/v2', 'abc.com/er.tyre.6/title/86348', 'ab.com/test/ertg.yeg/title/86348', 'abc.com/feed?app_id=57655', 'bcd.ru/467', 'abc.com/shth/5583628', 'abc.com/jhydhf']
```

С помощью кода

```
urls = [url for url in urls if re.search(r'((abc\.com/|ab\.com/)+[\.a-zA-Z\d]+(/title/\d{5})+)', url) and not re.search(r'[?=%-]', url)]
```

Получаю следующий результат

```
['abc.com/er.tyre.6/title/86348']
```

Чего не хватает в регулярке, чтобы 'ab.com/test/ertg.yeg/title/86348' тоже вошла в итоговый список?

test - это слово, которое может встретиться в ссылке 0 или 1 раз

P.S. вчера задавала подобный вопрос, но не до конца разобралась

Comment: я так понимаю, не "test", а "title"?

Comment: нет, title должен быть всегда, и для этого слова я написала правило в регулярке. а нужно чтобы и test после первого / был, 0 или 1 раз

Comment: Попробуйте вынести слеш в конце каждого варианта из второй группы `(abc\.com|ab\.com)` и убрав лишний квантификатор `+`  добавить следующую часть в группу и поставить в группу слеш в начало, после чего группе укажите квантификатор `{1,2}` : `(/[\.a-zA-Z\d]+){1,2}`. Пример: https://regex101.com/r/JUTfYw/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуем разобраться что не так с выражением:

```
((abc\.com/|ab\.com/)+[\.a-zA-Z\d]+(/title/\d{5})+)
```

Сама по себе группа `(abc\.com/|ab\.com/)` отличается только одним символом `c` в адресе, ее можно заменить на `abc?\.com/` - вопросительный знак в данном случае является квантификатором на 0 или 1 вхождение предыдущего символа.
Так же, в случае если test - это статичная часть url и должна всегда быть такой где адрес состоит из четырех вложенностей, то следует добавить новую группу `(test/)?` c квантификатором аналогичный 0 или 1 вхождение. Группу можно сделать не захватываемой добавив в начале группы `?:`. Тогда выражение будет иметь вид:

```
(abc?\.com/(?:test/)?[\.a-zA-Z\d]+(/title/\d{5}))
```

Пример: [regex101.com/v2](https://regex101.com/r/JUTfYw/2)

Если же вложенность адреса `test` не статичная и имя не известно, то следует сделать новую группу `(?:/[\.a-zA-Z\d]+){1,2}` поставив квантификатор на 1 или 2 совпадения. Тогда выражение будет иметь вид:

```
(abc?\.com(?:/[\.a-zA-Z\d]+){1,2}(/title/\d{5}))
```

Пример: [regex101.com/v1](https://regex101.com/r/JUTfYw/1)

upd после комментария: Если адреса подразумеваются разные, типа domain.com/ или niamod.ru, то группу конечно же нужно оставить:

```
//для первого случая
((?:abc\.com|ab\.com)/(?:test/)?[\.a-zA-Z\d]+(/title/\d{5}))

//для второго случая
((?:abc\.com|ab\.com)(?:/[\.a-zA-Z\d]+){1,2}(/title/\d{5}))
```

Comment: (abc\.com/|ab\.com/), я наверно не очень удачный пример привела. если допустить, что там будут два разных слова, то регулярка будет иметь вид ((abc\.com|ryeu\.com)/(?:test/)?[\.a-zA-Z\d]+(/title/\d{5}))?

Comment: @ЕленаСергеева да, структура выражения на мой взгляд верная, в ответе оставил отметку об этом